# How to randomly choose a certain number of elements in a list with non-uniform probability distribution without repetition?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list with 10 elements, I would like to choose 4 elements from the list randomly according to a certain probability distribution that I assign to, without repetition.

I know that there is a function numpy.random.choice, however this function allows repetition of choosing elements. How can the function of numpy.random.choice without repetition be achieved in a simple way?

Comment: use `replace=False` in your call to `choice()`.

Comment: use the p parameter of the function to assign the probability distribution

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just need to set the `replace` argument to `False` in `np.random.choice()`.  Like this:

```
np.random.seed(123) # for reproducibility

np.random.choice(range(10), replace=False, size=4)
# array([4, 0, 7, 5])
```